# What type of connector do laptop webcam modules use?

Tags: connector, serial

I'm trying to do a home practice with some used old laptop webcam, the model is "BA59-02608A" and it is from a Samsung NP-N150, it came without cable so I have no clue how could I connect to it, as I have never seen such kind of connector, I thought it might be a JST but I think I am wrong, I even asked Samsung but they didn't show much help.

[image]

Comment: Not standardized. Sorry, no answer can be given, it's the connector that exactly your laptop uses.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a 1mm FPC 5p cable and plugs with matching socket as shown in SMT. Pins are likely V+ RGB and 0V.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, but I didn't understand the part about matching socket as shown in SMT, should I go to try in person? otherwhise how can I be sure it will work.

Comment: I assumed with FPC plug at both ends , you need same socket at both ends.

Comment: Do you know what a FPC ribbon looks like with an insert plug? If not I guess you have to replace with your own 1mm cable + connectors

Comment: Thanks, so can I from that FPC, build and usb connector? so in one way I would connect the webcam and in the other would be able to connect to my computer

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Hirose or JAE connector.

That's not a MOLEX connector because there's no mating retention that was patented by Molex.

Post another couple of pictures.

Comment: thanks, here you go another picture, I hope it helps you
[first](https://i.imgur.com/yTevBXN.png)
[second](https://i.imgur.com/aazRi7B.png)
[third](https://i.imgur.com/UFtvlTT.png)

Comment: I can't help you.